# Jquery slidedown not sliding; instead, replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I am trying to write a little script that - one by one - grabs some pre-made divs out of an array of divs, puts them on the page, and then slides each of them down. The goal is to end up with something [like this](http://motyarlabs.blogspot.com/2010/09/foursquare-like-animated-feeds-with.html), but for a potentially large and dynamic number of divs.

Here's the function I'm using ("list" is my array of divs):

```
function popMsg(){
        var popped = list.pop(); 
        $(popped).appendTo("#chatframe").addClass("sliding");
        $(".sliding").slideDown(1000);
        setTimeout(popMsg, 1000);
    }
```

It is working in terms of getting the divs on the page, but the slidedown doesn't happen. Instead, each div replaces the last, just layering one on top of another. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and am totally out of ideas.

Comment: can u show the rest of the code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Since you're not removing the "sliding" class, the slideDown would be called on all of the elements in the list each time. Have you tried cutting out the sliding class and just fire slideDown immediately?
$(popped).appendTo("#chatframe").slideDown(1000);
Or add a callback to slideDown that removes the sliding class.

Comment: never used jsfiddle before, but does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/5hT3h/

Comment: here is ur functional fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/5hT3h/1/

Comment: thanks Effata ... I'm not super familiar with slideDown, but I think I want all of the elements in the list to slide down. I need them to slide down one after another (this is a chat-like thing), which is why I did that setTimeout. Also, if they were all sliding together now, wouldn't they all move? Right now, they just layer on top of one another in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Gah! Figured it out. I was doing two insanely stupid things:

a) I had the css for .sliding set to absolute. I changed it to relative.

b) I needed prependTo instead of appendTo. This makes each div push down the ones before it.

It's now working like a dream.